# I have a list of numbers using " private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list" and I want to sum them

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="Brand";
public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Model";
public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Total";

public void addDeleteItemList() {

    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    final ListViewAdapter adapter0=new ListViewAdapter(this,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter0);

    txtInput = findViewById(R.id.cantitateID);
    txtInput2 = findViewById(R.id.specieID);
    txtInput3 = findViewById(R.id.sortimentID);
    Button but = findViewById(R.id.addID);
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HashMap<String,String> hashmap=new HashMap<String, String>();

            String  newItem = txtInput2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String  newItem2 = txtInput3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String  newItem3 = txtInput.getText().toString();

            hashmap.put(FIRST_COLUMN, newItem);
            hashmap.put(SECOND_COLUMN, newItem2);
            hashmap.put(THIRD_COLUMN, newItem3);
            list.add(hashmap);
            adapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
                sum+= list.get(i);
            }
            et_volumTotal.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        }
    });
}
```

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '+' first type:  int
>   second type: HashMap

[image]

Comment: You can not do calculations with hashmaps. It is properly saying you receive first int and another hashmap

Comment: how can i calculate the sum?

Comment: i don't see any integer inside your hashmap by looking your image i can say your hashmap key might be skoda and values is car name

Comment: Please explain your problem means what you want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get `THIRD_COLUMN` from `HashMap` and then convert it to `int`. After that you can sum it up. Check below:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++) { 

    int value = 0;
    try {
        value = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    sum += value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! 
It works perfectly. Sorry if I did not express myself correctly